# Getting 2 accordion headings instead of 1

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create an accordion type of menu. What I have at the moment is a column in the database that looks like
`menu 1/sub menu 1` and in my function I explode that to create an array that looks something like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "menu 1"
  1 => "sub menu 1"
]
```

At the moment I'm not sure how to add the sub menu inside the accordion.

This is what I have at the moment:

```html
@foreach($m['explode'] as $k => $m)
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $m }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                {{ $m }}
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="{{ $m }}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ $m }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

What happens is that I get 2 accordion headings instead of 1. It's also possible to have more than 2 items in an array.

Comment: you should change `$k => $v` or something, but not `$k => $m`, because `$m` is already defined and its rewrite the `$m['explode']`, so your loop stop on the first loop, when `$m` redefined with new data

Comment: I've changed `$k => $m` to `$k => $v` but I'm still getting 2 headings instead of 1

Comment: You'll still get 2 because you have two items in the array and the way you have implemented them.  And yes, you can have more than 2 values in an array.,

Comment: @OMiShah - I get that, but how do I make it in such a way that I can have something like this `level 1 = menu 1` anad `level 2 = sub menu 1`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Instead of ``foreach`` you can directly access ``$m['explode'][0]`` as main menu and then [1] as sub menu.

Comment: but what if there is more

Comment: Then make your own logic how you're going to differentiate a sub menu from a list of items without any specific key modifier for sub menu or main menu.